# counting of unique entries of 2 columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following table:

```
Schema::create('tracks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('ip');
        $table->string('session');
        $table->string('roboname')->nullable();
        $table->string('language');
        $table->string('referer');
        $table->string('path');
        $table->string('device');
        $table->string('screensize');
        $table->string('browser');
        $table->string('browser_version');
        $table->string('os');
        $table->string('os_version');
        $table->string('url');
        $table->string('full_url');
        $table->boolean('is_mobile');
        $table->boolean('is_tablet');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

i want to count all unique entries of session and path. What is the best way to do this?
example:

```
session | path
123 /test
123 /test1
123 /test
321 /test
321 /test
```

The result here would be 3.

Comment: This isn't a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have 2 columns  `session , path`  you could use   count distinct for a concat

```
 select count(distinct concat(session,path)) my_count 
 from  my_table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use next solution:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT session, path) FROM tracks;
```

This query return count of distinct compositions of session and path

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count discount ifnull` on Eloquent like this:

```php
Track::select(DB::raw("COUNT(DISTINCT IFNULL(session, ''), IFNULL(path, '')) AS session_path_count"))
      ->first()
      ->session_path_count;
```